# Join condition syntax for comparing a sequence of digits

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, one of which has a 2 digit `customerId` integer column and another one that has a `transactionId` integer column. The second and third digits of the `transactionId` column correspond to `customerId`s. I would like to perform a join on the two tables with by 'matching' the `transactionId` and `customerId` as the join condition. Something like

`customerId LIKE '_transactionId%`

Is this possible?

Comment: What data-types are these fields?   Is your use of `LIKE` implying that these are actually VARCHAR fields that just happen to hold integers?  Or are they actually an INT data-type?  Does this need to be be quick, or is it just a one-off that can be slow but simple to code?  Are you able to modify the schema at all? *(Your description implies that there should be a composite key made from at least two fields, rather than one field holding multiple values jammed in together)*

Comment: They are integers but could be modified to be VARCHAR. Would creating the table with these as VARCHAR increase efficiency? That is, are INT data-types case into VARCHAR types when we're using LIKE?

Comment: In this very particular case you would likely see a benefit in using VARCHAR instead of INT.  This is because they are indeed having to be implicitly coerced to a VARCHAR in order to have the LIKE operator act on them, and that coercion prohibits the database engine from using any indexes.  If they are/were VARCHAR then you could have something like `transactionId IN (CONCAT('0', customerId), CONCAT('1', customerId), CONCAT('2', customerId), ... CONCAT('9', customerId))`.  But that's an optimisation for a weak design pattern.

Comment: A better design pattern would be for the TransactionID to be stored across multiple fields *(one of which being the CustomerID part of the TransactionID)*, instead of having the CustomerID embedded in the TransactionID field.  Then you get many benefits; You can set up a foreign key constraint so that all such record Must point to a valid Customer, you can index the CustomerID separately from any other field, you keep the IDs as Integers without having to compromise to account for perverse join conditions, you're not constrained to 00..99 customers, etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right idea:

```
on transactionId like concat('_', customerId, %)
```

Alternatively, you could use `substr()`:

```
on customerId = substr(transactionId, 2, 2)
```

However, you should probably fix your data structure so the transactions have an explicit column for the customer id.  This will help the joins go faster.  And, when you start to get more than 99 customers, your data structure will adapt.

Comment: Would up-vote twice if I could; an answer than helps, and advice that the design has flaws, and how to address them.

Comment: I think it should be reversed: `on transactionId like concat('_', customerId, '%')`